# Execute threads in order in C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# program to winform application. It is intended as a memory game. First I have to show a matrix with  number of values inside it. say 3 or 4. I have to pause the matrix for a while so that user saves it in his memory. For that I use thread1. Then I need to blank the matrix and show some options on the right panel of form. It is done using Thread2. The problem now is actually thread2 is executed first. Can anyone help me please.I am new to C#...

```
Thread Thread1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(invokedisplaymatrix));
Thread1.IsBackground = true;
Thread1.Start(MatrixInfoValues);


            Thread Thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(invokedisplayblankmatrix));
            Thread2.IsBackground = true;
            Thread2.Start();
}

 private void invokedisplaymatrix(object indx)
            {
    Invoke(new displaymatrixdelegate(displaymatrix),new object[] {indx});

Thread.sleep(5000);
              }

private void invokedisplayblankmatrix()
        {
Invoke(new displayblankmatrixdelegate(displayblankmatrix));
         }...

.. public delegate void displaymatrixdelegate(int[] ind1);
    public delegate void displayblankmatrixdelegate();
}//end of main form
```

Comment: Threads run *concurrently* - they do what they will with the CPU available to them. If you want them to be *in order*, you probably meant a work queue, not separate threads.

Answer (score 5):

Create Thread2 and start it at the end of invokedisplaymatrix.

I'm not sure why you're using threads if there isn't meant to be any concurrency going on, however.

Comment: Could you please suggest me how to do it in a timer/ any other code?Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at the [TPL](http://www.google.bg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CF8QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx&ei=_Z7MT9aVA8TYsga7p_jOBg&usg=AFQjCNGjTfP3C9wE1gKSbCEzZlCOZrAYkA). Tasks support your scenario out of the box(via the [ContinueWith](http://www.google.bg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CFAQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx&ei=K5_MT7juMY_MswaRoezxBg&usg=AFQjCNEHjfMATuQYkoaiiJHKefY6ARkO6w) method).

I'm not sure why do you need 2 threads here though - threads are good to use when doing parallel work, which doesn't look like the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use AutoResetEvent to implement it.

So...

```
var sync = new AutoResetEvent();

var thread1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(invokedisplaymatrix));
thread1.IsBackground = true;
thread1.Start(MatrixInfoValues);


thread Thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(invokedisplayblankmatrix));
thread2.IsBackground = true;
thread2.Start();

private void invokedisplaymatrix(object indx)
{
  Invoke(new displaymatrixdelegate(displaymatrix),new object[] {indx});
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  sync.Set();
}

private void invokedisplayblankmatrix()
{
  sync.Wait();
  Invoke(new displayblankmatrixdelegate(displayblankmatrix));
}
```

But you don't need separete threads to implement this case, this is simple one thread task.

Comment: I was not able to declare autoreset event.Could you plese advise me how it can be done using single thread?I need to show the matrix displayed for 5 sec and then display options of answers in the answer panel. thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use Timer to perform this operation

Answer (score 0):

Look at System.Threading.Semaphore:

in this sample we need to run "work2" delegate fisrt:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var sem = new Semaphore(0, 1);

    Action<object> work1 = o =>
    {
        sem.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("enter " + o);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("exit " + o);
    };

    Action<object> work2 = o =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enter " + o);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("exit " + o);
        sem.Release();
    };

    work1.BeginInvoke("first", ar => { }, null);
    work2.BeginInvoke("second", ar => { }, null);       

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```